# Is there an algorithm that imputes missing values based on n nearest columns? (KNN hybrid)

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, k-nn

I have a dataset of 70 columns that have missing values. Each column has a few columns (3-5) that it is significantly more correlated than the others but each column's correlated columns are very different from other columns. I would like to perform a tweaked version of KNN imputation and before I start writing this from scratch, I'd like to know if there's something similar out there, So, I don't go about reinventing the wheel.

*On initialization, a correlation matrix is obtained between all the variables. For every missing cell that needs to be imputed, the algorithm retrieves from the correlation matrix the top n highest correlated columns and uses **only those N columns** to select the k nearest neighbors and use the mean value of those neighbors.*

Thanks and apologies if I am not very clear with my question. I'll try to clarify if you have any doubts.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of such a package already existing but I think it is an interesting idea. If computationally it is not to heavy maybe you can also test to calculate the distance by weighting them with their correlation.

Comment: Use a for-loop on each column - 1. to select your N Columns and 2. use sklearn.impute.KNNImputer as suggested by @Brian to predict and fill the missing values

Answer (score 2):

You can extend scikit-learn's [`sklearn.impute.KNNImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html). The `metric` parameter can accept the custom function you described.